# Choppy Image on multithreaded android game

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es, synchronization

I decided to convert my spritesbased 2d game for android to use opengl-es to help with some render-related framerate issues.  Currently the setup is as follows:

Rendering tkaes place in its own thread, with rendermode set to continuous.  Game logic updating takes place in a seperate threaad.  Both threads interact with a synchronized drawlock class which ensures that they are never touching the game information simultaneously.

So basically, the render thread waits for any current update to finish before drawing and the update thread waits for the current render to end before starting an update.  Everything looks great except or some choppiness I've noticed in the picture when moving around the screen.

I believe this is likely due to a lack of consistency in the number of updates that happen in between each render, on average twice as many updates happen because as of right now not a whole lot is happening in the update.  But this lacks consistency so sometimes 1 gets through, sometimes 2, 3 etc so the delta in positions of items being drawn is also not consistent thus creating the choppiness.

Anyone have an idea how I might rectify this?  The update thread is regulated to 60 times per second with sleeps...maybe something similar needs to happen under render?  I'm just not sure at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how voluminous your game data is, you might try replicating it. While the game engine is updating one copy, the rendering engine is working off the other. When an update is finished, the rendering engine switches to reading the updated copy while the game engine waits until the updates are transferred to the older copy (which the engine will then update on the next cycle). It's kind of a double-buffering approach, but applied to the game data instead of to the display buffer.

Comment: hmm that's really smart actually...having a little trouble wrapping my head around it though.  Are you saying that the update changes which set of data to render from every time it finishes?  So this could potentially happen in the middle of a render?  Just by changing the data set it's pointing to it immediately starts drawing at the new positions?

Comment: The change-over would probably have to be synchronized. If the game data is small enough, you could use three copies: one for the game engine to update, one for the render engine to read, and one for the game engine to switch to when it finishes an update. The right number of copies could be determined by profiling where the bottlenecks actually are.

Comment: so i guess one of the main problems Im running into is the "choppiness" im referring to is actually just inconsistency of the number of updates happening per render, so while the update thread is updating an objects position to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, my rendere is hitting it haphazardly and displaying positions at 1, 4, 5, 6, 9 or something so its not a clean uniform scrolling because renders take longer than the updates.  I need to somehow be able to make it so the renderer accesses the data at uniform points in the timeline, at 2, 4, 6, 8, etc to achieve smooth scrolling and movement.

Comment: Ah. My approach isn't going to help with that after all. How about throttling the updates so that at most one update happens between renderings? One way is to use a shared variable `rendered` that is set to `true` by the rendering thread and `false` by the updating thread. When it is false, the update thread waits and when the rendering thread sets it to true, it notifies all waiting threads.

Comment: Yeah i started looking into that but then realized that maybe i should be looking at why render loops take 80-90ms to execute...anyways thanks for your help :)